# Converting nested json to csv in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

The given nested json is an true example of json being used and i need to extract only [a2] and its [pp] [qq] [rr] in the given json data.

```
    {
       "aa":1500,
       "bb":1570,
       "cc":"14",
       "a1":{
          "x":1065,
          "y":9040.0,
          "z":[
             {
                "pp":1596,
                "qq":1.00,
                "rr":1400,
             },
             {
                "pp":15960000,
                "qq":1.00,
                "rr":1400,
             }
          ]
      },       
      "a2":{
         "x":324,
         "y":342.0,
         "z":[
            {
               "pp":15960,
               "qq":1.00,
               "rr":1.00,
            },
            {
               "pp":31434,
               "qq":1500,
               "rr":1500,
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried multiple syntax for the same but always encounted some error .Anyone who clould provide a possible solution to this json to csv conversion in python and create a new csv file to write that csv output in it  .

Comment: i am getting an error of string indices must be an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
x['a2']['z']

[{'pp': 15960, 'qq': 1.0, 'rr': 1.0}, {'pp': 31434, 'qq': 1500, 'rr': 1500}]
```

Comment: if a2 is a tree of that given json it has branches x,y,z and pp qq rr are sub branches of z so basically i want all of z of a2 in csv .

Comment: yes thats right

Answer (score 0):

Let's name your file `foo.json` and try to access `a2`, `z`, and the first of both `[pp] [qq] [rr]`

```py
import json

with open("foo.json", "r") as filein:
    json_file = json.loads(filein.read())

z = json_file["a2"]["z"]
pp = z[0]["pp"]
# and so on
```

Comment: if a2 is a tree of that given json it has branches x,y,z and pp qq rr are sub branches of z so basically i want all of z of a2 in csv

Comment: If you are trying to get both `[pp][qq][rr]` you can do it with z[0] for the first ones and z[1] for the second ones. I think that's what you are asking.